# Converting part of a char* into an int

Tags: c, char, int, fgets

I am trying to convert part of a char* into an int. For example if a user inputs 'step 783'. I want to convert 783 into an int.

```
char buffer[100];
char* input = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)
int i = input[5] - '0'; //assume location 5 is where the number will start
printf("%i", i);
```

Right now, this code just prints out the first number ('7').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ordinary conversion functions, starting at the desired position:

```
int i = atoi(input + 5);
long int j = strtol(input + 5, NULL, 0);
```

The second one, `strtol()`, is particularly useful if you want to find out where the number *ended* (via the second parameter, [see manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)).

Comment: Thanks Kerrek and Mystical (saw your answer too). I will try this out. I have heard of atoi but not strtoul. strtoul will be really helpful for me for a different part of my program. Thanks again!

Comment: As an addendum, if the number is only a part of the string, use `strncpy` to copy it to a temporary string. And don't forget to add the terminating `'\0'` character to the end.

Comment: Hmm... that makes sense. Thanks for help! Just out of curiosity, what would be the benefits of using strncopy to have the number in a temporary string? Using Kerrek's answer above, I could go to that location in a string to convert it into an int.

Comment: @RyanBridge: If `input` was `"ab12cd"` then using the `atoi` or `strtoul` on `input + 2` would work. But if `input` is `"123456`" and you want just the `"34"` you have to copy it to a temporary string first.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. Fortunately I dont have to worry about such input but I'll keep this in my mind for future use. Thanks Joachim!

Comment: @RyanBridge: `strtoul()` and the entire family (`strtof/d/q` and `strtol/ll/ul/ull`) is generally preferable over `atoi`. It offers the same functionality with more control and error checking. (The `ll` versions are C99/C++11 I believe.)

Answer (score 1):

If always there is a space before the number and always the words are two like "step 123".

then below is the code that works.

```
int main ()
{
  char str[] ="tring 7532";
  char *pch1,*pch2;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch1 = strtok (str," ");
  pch2= strtok (NULL, " ");
  int a=strtol(pch2,(char **)NULL,10);

  printf ("the number is: %d\n",a);

return 0;
}

264> ./a.out
Splitting string "tring 7532" into tokens:
the number is: 7532
```

Comment: This is pretty useful for what im trying to do. I was going to just go through every character and look for an empty space. Thanks for the help Rahul!

Answer (score 0):

You don't define well what you mean part of a string? Is it always the 6th character -of index 5?

You could use [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi), or perhaps [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

Comment: Yes, it always starts at the 6th character of the user input. Hmm, I'll definitely check out those fucntions. Thanks Basile!

Answer (score 0):

Because you just convert the first digit.

if it's always a 3-digit number:

```
int i = 100 * int(input[5] - '0') + 10 * int(input[5] - '0') + int(input[5] - '0')
```

Comment: Its not always a 3 digit number but i understand what your are trying to do. Would it be input[5] then [6] then [7]?

Answer (score 0):

you have to move from start to end and check if it comes under digit ascii then convert it into digit

```
    int digit = 0; i = 0;
    while(input[i] != '\0'){
     if(input[i] >= 48 && input[i] <= 57){

       int temp = input[i] - '0';
       digit  = digit*10 + temp;

     }
    i++;
    }
printf("%i", digit);
```

Comment: Hmm.. I think using atoi or strtoul might be easier but I get what you are doing here. Thanks for the help Ashish!

Answer (score 0):

You can technically use one of proposed methods, but it might happen that you will need some kind of parser, if you want really robust handling.

You should check if you have keyword "step", then space, and then number in valid format for your input.

For example: what if user enters just "s 1" instead of "step 1". Do you want to start reading after end of input? Or if he enters "step[space][space]-2342344234234234233333" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *p;
int i;
p = strchr(input, ' ');
i = atoi(p);
```